# Can I prevent my web host provider access information in my "mySQL" database?

Tags: php, mysql, security, web-hosting

I was wondering if I could prevent my web host provider from accessing information in my "mySQL" database.

For example, if I embed a PHPBB forum engine into my website, is there a way I can prevent the employees working for the hots provider access the confidential details posted on my forums? I know that PHPBB stores the database credentials in a human readable config file which kinda makes it futile to protect the database with a password...

Many thanks!

Comment: You can never really prevent that as long as you use some cloud service. That is a general flaw of that approach. You kind of present your private data on a tablet for others.  The only alternative approach is to run your own server, but even then you cannot really guarantee that no one else has access. Especially the secret services of the US and their allies claim they have every right to spy into your private data on your private devices. And certainly they do have the means to do so.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I guess running my own server would be way too costly as compared to paying for dedicated hosting... or am I wrong?

Comment: Consider running an instance on AWS http://aws.amazon.com/. Depending on what you are doing in terms of CPU and Disk needs it starts from around 40-50USD per month for a fully accessible linux install with LAMP installed.

Comment: @arkascha __Especially the secret services of the US and their allies claim they have every right to spy into your private data on your private devices. And certainly they do have the means to do so__ I'm not afraid about these guys but more about those script kiddies out there trying to steal user credentials and CC accounts. Having a service on the net currently means 10-15% load is coming from those (erroneous) attempts. Annoying...

Comment: A simple but decent VPS comes at about 15 Euros a month and you have the choice of the location of the data center (from a legal point of view). AWS is fine for companies because of the scalability and reliability. But apart from that it is really expensive.

Comment: @AxelAmthor OK, if that is your only concern, then it does not matter where you host your data.

Comment: @arkascha That's not quite true. Sensible data belongs behind a firwall in your own hosting facility. But even there, root is `root` by all means. And NSA can pass any firewall, if they want.

Comment: @AxelAmthor What does a firewall have to do with data access on a system? And what do you mean by "own hosting facility"? Apart from that I doubt very much that the NSA "can pass any firewall". If a service is not reachable it is not reachable, no matter what you try. But why should they? They do not have to. You use the network, much easier to capture your data there. The issue is the proprietary firmware on the embedded controllers and their access to the networks backbone nodes.

Comment: Thanks all for your replies. I gave it some thought and I'm now contemplating setting up my own server. How difficult could it be?

Comment: I am currently developing my website on a Unix BSD machine running Appache (using the underlying OS on an iMac machine). I can test the website on my own home LAN and that includes testing it on mobile devices. However, I have never exposed anything to the internet yet and I'm not sure what to expect. In respect to the "production" sever I might setup a Linux running Nginx instead of Apache. Any opinions on this? Or should I stick with the Apache running on BSD?

Answer (score 1):

> I was wondering if I could prevent my web host provider from accessing
>   information in my "mySQL" database.

**No.**

As long as you host your site you cannot be sure. Yes, there might be some legal rights/terms/agreements that they won't do it but still... They have all the *root* (or other privileged user) credentials to be able to do whatever they like on their servers (and this also applies to VS/VM providers).

Comment: This is the correct answer. There are ways to set up security that the providers can't tamper with (i.e. [Tahoe-LAFS](https://leastauthority.com)), but typically not in the context of a web application.

Comment: What about situation when Mysql is hosted and created on VPS and all Mysql users and their credentials are owned and controled by the Customer? i.e. Mysql root user and password is known only to Customer  (and thus not known to hosting provider) ? Web Host provider can have mysql db files, but they aren't readable from outside?